# No. of integer solutions to a quadratic eq with three variab

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Here is the equation:
$$z=18*18*18x^2 y^2+18*14*18x^2 y+ 18*49x^2+ 18*25y^2+ 18*10*18*18xy^2+ 36*71xy+37*7x+ 360y+71$$
I know it has obvious solution like $(0,0,71)$ for $(x,y,z)$. 
Have also found other solutions, like $(0,1,881)$ for $(x,y,z)$. I wonder if there is a 
general approach to show that there are many solutions of 
the form ???

Comment: my first thought is parity arguments because all but two terms are even so any time x is odd the value of z is even.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ can take any values. Calculate the RHS to get the value for $z$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit we don't even need to if we are looking for 0's z will not equal an even number unless x is odd they are of opposite parity so just by knowing parity of x and y you can show z's parity and check if it could be 0.

Comment: Most likely would be deleting the $z=$ part and asking whether there are any pairs $(x,y)$ of integers that make the big expression $0.$

Comment: So my general question would have no straight answer. The general equation would be:  if there is a general approach for the equations like $$ax^2 y^2+bx^2 y+cxy^2+dx^2+ey^2+fxy+hx+iy+j=0$$ ?